# Metis installation

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, metis

I am totally new in ubuntu and metis and I am trying to install metis in ubuntu. I could not find any suitable tutorial.
firstly, I downloaded CMake 2.8.9 and I tried to install CMake using following codes:

`cd cmake-2.8.9
./configure --help
./configure --prefix=opt/cmake`

Then I tried to install metis:

```
   cd metis-5.1.0
   make config
```

but I received an error

```
user@user:~/metis-5.1.0$ make config
rm -rf build/Linux-x86_64
mkdir -p build/Linux-x86_64
cd build/Linux-x86_64 && cmake /home/user/metis-5.1.0 -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=1 -DGKLIB_PATH=/home/user/metis-5.1.0/GKlib
/bin/sh: 1: cmake: not found
make: *** [config] Error 127
```

Cis it possible to help me regarding metis installation step by step. 
Many thanks

Comment: It seems you forget to add `cmake` executable into your PATH.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Unless the METIS software explicitly call for this old version of CMake, I'd consider upgrading to something newer. The latest CMake is available [here](https://cmake.org/download/). The error says `cmake` is not found, so you have not installed it correctly. Did you add the path to your `cmake` executable to your `Path` environment variable?

Comment: @Skh You also need to compile and install CMake and not just configure. You are missing the `make` and `make install` commands above. That said, it is generally more preferable to use the official repositories: `sudo apt install cmake`.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I tried to install CMake again. I didn't receive the same error. But I've received an error after executing "make install ". Then I switched to the root by executing this command.  " $ sudo su" and repeated all the steps again. I didn't get an error. Now how can I understand metis is installed or not? the last line is as bellow: make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sahar/metis-5.1.0/build/Linux-x86_64'

Comment: @Skh If there are no error messages in the `make install` output then presumably it was installed correctly. Try to use it somewhere and see if it works. Since I haven't used metis myself I can't help much with the details.